# JMockit - Expectations vs MockUp<T> Why does one work and the other doesn't?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

I'm attempting (still) to learn the ins and outs of JMockit.  Here's yet another example of a JMockit oddity I just don't get.  Running the test with NonStrictExpectations works just fine.  However, running with MockUp does not.  I'm not sure why.  Any ideas?  I'm running JMockit 1.5.

Method to test:

```
private List<Foo> getFooList(List<FooStatement> fooStatements){
    List<Foo> FooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();

    for(FooStatement at: fooStatements){
        List<Foo> aList = at.getFoos();
        FooList.addAll(aList);
    }

    return FooList;
}
```

Successful Expectations Test

```
@Test
public void getFooListWithExpectationsTest(
        @Mocked final FooStatement mockFooStatement,
        @Mocked final Foo mockFoo
){

    List<FooStatement> fooStatementList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            mockFooStatement,
            mockFooStatement
    ));

    new NonStrictExpectations(){{
        mockFooStatement.getFoos();
        result = new ArrayList<Foo>(Arrays.asList(mockFoo));
    }};

    List<Foo> fooList = Deencapsulation.invoke(handler, "getFooList", fooStatementList);
    Assert.assertTrue(fooList.size() == 2);
}
```

Assertions Error (0 != 2) with MockUp

```
@Test
public void getFooListWithMockUpTest(
        @Mocked final FooStatement mockFooStatement,
        @Mocked final Foo mockFoo
){

    new MockUp<FooStatement>(){
        @Mock
        public List<Foo> getFoos(){
            return new ArrayList<Foo>(Arrays.asList(mockFoo));
        }
    };

    List<FooStatement> fooStatementList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            mockFooStatement,
            mockFooStatement
    ));

    List<Foo> fooList = Deencapsulation.invoke(handler, "getFooList", fooStatementList);
    Assert.assertTrue(fooList.size() == 2);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `MockUp<?>` incorrectly. `MockUp<T?` will tell JMockit to redefine a classes loaded to JVM so that instead of the real class initialization of `FooStatement`, it will replace them by the ones defined in the `MockUp<FooStatement`.

**So basically `MockUp<FooStatement>` will automatically replace calls of `new FooStatement()`.**

Try something like:

```
@Test
public void getFooListWithMockUpTest(@Mocked final Foo mockFoo){

    new MockUp<FooStatement>(){
        @Mock
        public List<Foo> getFoos(){
            return new ArrayList<Foo>(Arrays.asList(mockFoo));
        }
    };

    List<FooStatement> fooStatementList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            new FooStatement(),
            new FooStatement()
    ));

    List<Foo> fooList = Deencapsulation.invoke(handler, "getFooList",     fooStatementList);
    Assert.assertTrue(fooList.size() == 2);
}
```

Comment: Ah.  That would make sense.  FooStatement is an interface though so that means every time I instantiate one, I'd have to implement all of its methods.  Doesn't seem new MockUp<T> is the way to go in this instance then.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is there a way to use MockUp<T> to only mock method calls?  I guess that would be what Expectations would be for if not.

Comment: You don't normally use both the Expectations API *and* the Mockups API in the same test. They are different APIs for different needs. "Expectations" is for behavior-oriented unit tests where you focus on method calls from the class under test to its collaborators, while "Mockups" is for fake implementations used in state-oriented tests.

Comment: MockUp is deprecated. Please use Expectations. Please checkout official github page  jmockit.github.io/changes.html

Answer (score -3):

MockUp is deprecated, use Expectations

Comment: Can you provide your source?

Comment: Please check: https://jmockit.github.io/changes.html Version 1.39 (Mar 25, 2018):
Removed the MockUp#getMockInstance() method, which was deprecated in version 1.37. Clearly official documentation says to NOT to use MockUp

Comment: Version 1.37 (Nov 26, 2017): Deprecated the getMockInstance() method from the MockUp class. Normally, this method is only used to obtain an instance of a faked interface. For faked classes, it has no practical use. Instead of using a mock-up for an interface type, it's recommended to create a minimal implementation class, or to use an existing implementation.

It doesn't mention anything about Not to use MockUp, it says to not use MockUp to make a mock for an interface.